# Ubuntu 20.04 keeps goes to sleep

Tags: suspend, power-management, hibernate

I recently installed Ubuntu 20.04 on Razer Blade Pro 17, but I am having a problem with the laptop constantly being put to sleep after I put it to sleep in the first place.

I can boot into Ubuntu, and OS works normally. I can put it to sleep/close a lid, and everything goes fine still. However, when I awake it again, it will work for around 15s and then go to sleep again.

I have tried playing around with settings even switching off Automatic Suspend option in the settings, but with no luck.

Update:
After digging through logs, I've found that ACPI throws this error around the time system goes to sleep:

```
ACPI Error: AE_NOT_EXIST, While executing method \_WAK (20190816/hwesleep-47)
```

Comment: any solutions to this? I have the exact same problem

Comment: I found the answer some time ago and posted it here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution on [this github repo](https://github.com/rolandguelle/razer-blade-stealth-linux/blob/master/ubuntu-18-10.md#11-suspend-loop), which also contains some other useful resources for Linux on Razer laptops.

Solution is to add `button.lid_init_state=open` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` argument in `/etc/default/grub` and then `sudo update-grub`.

To get rid of ACPI error, you might also want to add `acpi=on` or `acpi=hybrid` to the same boot options. This can solve an issue with touchpad not responding.

Comment: Hi balbok, thank you so much! Is there any chance you could expand on what you mean by "adding"? Do you mean changing e.g. from `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash button.lid_init_state=open"`

Comment: Hi! Yes, that's what I meant by adding it to the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`